# how to access items by ForeignKey lookup field instead of pk?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In django rest framework(DRF) I want access items by Foreign Key lookup field instead of pk
url:\investment\< member >\

```
class InvestmentListViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Investment.objects.all()
    serializer_class = InvestmentSerializer
    lookup_field = 'member'
```

but have a error:

```
investment.models.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one 
Investment -- it returned 6!
```

This is my model and serializer

```
class Investment(models.Model):
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project)
    time = models.DateField(default=datetime.now)

class InvestmentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Investment
        fields = ('time','member', 'project')
```

how to use Foreign Key member  return a Investment list?

Comment: How did you tried. pasting your query will help us to understand better your problem.

Comment: include the full traceback with the code which is causing this error

Comment: sorry,my english is not good.
i want return a 'Investment' list ,use  'member'  lookup field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

imho best solution for current issue, is create `viewset` for your model `Member` with method `investments`, if not exist create **MemberSerializer**

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework.decorators import detail_route


class MemberViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Member.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MemberSerializer

    @detail_route(methods=['get'], )
    def investments(self, request, pk):
        qs = self.get_object().investment_set.all()
        serializer = InvestmentSerializer(qs, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

in urls.py

```
router.register(r'member', MemberViewSet)
```

and result you may get by url `/member/<member_pk>/investments/`

more details, [extra-link-and-actions](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#extra-link-and-actions)

hope it help you